# how to design routes for nesting resources in rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I want to create a web application.

1. one user has many articles;
2. one article has many comments;

The codes as below:

```
class User
  .....
  has_many :articles
end

class Article
 ....
 belongs_to :user
 embeds_many :comments
end

class Comment
  ....
  embedded_in :article, inverse_of: :comments
end
```

I want to use the nesting routes:

```
resources :users do
  resources :articles do
    resource :comments do
  end
end
```

But Rails Guide told us to avoid multiple nesting resource. Anyone can give me some good ideas. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can avoid deep nesting using `Shallow Nesting`.

```
resources :users do
  resources :articles, shallow: true do
    resources :comments
  end
end
```

It will give the same routes as:

```
resources :users do
  resources :articles, only: [:index, :new, :create]
end

resources :articles, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]
  resource :comments, only: [:index, :new, :create]
end

resource :comments, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]
```

and urls like this:

```
users/1
users/1/articles
articles/1
articles/1/edit
articles/1/comments
comments/1
comments/1/edit
```

You can read more about this here http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#nested-resources and play with it.

If you want to do it more simple and have urls like this (deeper nesting):

```
users/1
users/1/articles/1
users/1/articles/1/edit
articles/1/comments
articles/1/comments/1
articles/1/comments/1/edit
```

then you can do it this way:

```
resources users do
  resources :articles
end

resources articles, only: [] do
  resources :comments
end
```

Good luck and have fun!

Answer (score 0):

Since the relationship between users and articles is not many to many it would be redundant to specify routes for each article and it's comments from the parent.

```
resources users do
    resources :articles
end

resources articles, only: [] do
    resources :comments
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you should avoid to nest more that one ressource in another.

You can do this:

```
resources :users do
  resources :articles 
end
```

And this:

```
resources :articles do
  resource :comments
end
```

So a user has many articles, and articles have many comments.